# Display preview of dropped image in Image control in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, desktop-application

In my application i create a form which has an image control for which i have added drag drop event functionality.
My problem is that i want to display the user a preview of the form once the user drop in an image. I have written a method to grab a screenshot of the form and display it but i dont exactly know when to call this method.
If i call this method from within the Drop event then the sceenshot is of the previous state of the form. What i mean by that is if the Image control contains Image A as the initial image and the user drops image B into it, then calling my screenshot method give me a screenshot of the form having Image A.
I was hoping that is there a event in WPF which can tell me that my image rendering in the control is finished? I have already tried events like Loaded, SourceUpdated etc. but they dont seem to work.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to something likes below image. You should take a look at [How to drag and drop items between data bound ItemsControls](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/488).
[image]

Comment: That is not what i am looking for.